# how to get total count of particular value for each date in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
   @Ecode NVARCHAR(50),
   @startdate DATE,
   @enddate DATE 
AS BEGIN
   SELECT 
      e.Ecode, q.dtime, e.Ename, 
      count(q.Ecode) CntEcode, 
      count(DelEcode) CntDelEcode, 
      CAST((count(q.Ecode) + count(DelEcode)) as float)/2 as Avrgpoint
   FROM 
      EmployeeMaster_tbl e  
   INNER JOIN 
      Transaction_tbl q ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode 
   WHERE 
      q.Ecode = @Ecode
      AND dtime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
   GROUP BY
      e.Ecode, e.Ename, q.dtime 
   ORDER BY 
      e.Ecode DESC
END
```

while executing this: out put is getting like this:

```
Ecode   dtime                     Ename              CntEcode  CntDelEcode   Avrgpoint
E001    2013-05-25 12:55:23.000   Deepu M. Thomas       1           0           0.5
E001    2013-05-25 13:53:16.000   Deepu M. Thomas       1           0           0.5
E001    2013-05-27 03:24:59.000   Deepu M. Thomas       1           1           0.5
E001    2013-05-27 03:24:59.000   Deepu M. Thomas       1           0           0.5
E001    2013-05-28 03:24:59.000   Deepu M. Thomas       1           0           0.5
```

I want to get output totalcount of(CntEcode ,CntDelEcode ) for each date.expected out put like this:

```
Ecode   dtime         Ename               CntEcode    CntDelEcode 
E001    2013-05-25    Deepu M. Thomas        2            0            
E001    2013-05-27    Deepu M. Thomas        2            1          
E001    2013-05-28    Deepu M. Thomas        1            0
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: oke,,sir,,i will change that to date,

Comment: You can also convert the string to datetime while you are doing the group by . It will also give the similar result.

Comment: sir,,i cahnged my stored procedure what ever you said,but i am getting same answer only

Comment: dtime is the datetime datatype in my database

Comment: i changed like this: but error coming :Column 'Transaction_tbl.dtime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: see my response - you need to do this `CAST(dtime AS DATE)` in the `SELECT` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at just the date portion of `dtime`, use `CAST(dtime AS DATE)` to get just the date:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
   @Ecode NVARCHAR(50),
   @startdate DATE,
   @enddate DATE 
AS BEGIN
   SELECT 
      e.Ecode, 
      CAST(q.dtime AS DATE),      -- <== CAST to DATE
      e.Ename, 
      count(q.Ecode) CntEcode, 
      count(DelEcode) CntDelEcode, 
      CAST((count(q.Ecode) + count(DelEcode)) as float)/2 as Avrgpoint
   FROM 
      EmployeeMaster_tbl e  
   INNER JOIN 
      Transaction_tbl q ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode 
   WHERE 
      q.Ecode = @Ecode
      AND dtime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
   GROUP BY
      e.Ecode, e.Ename, 
      CAST(q.dtime AS DATE)    -- <== CAST to DATE here, too!
   ORDER BY 
      e.Ecode DESC
END
```